# Clearcase error : vobrpc_server.exe(<pid>): Error: See albd or vob error logs on host <host name>

Tags: clearcase

We are working on a task to resurrect a ClearCase server.
During the restoration process, we are stuck with following error as shown in server log.

```
vobrpc_server.exe(<pid>): Error: See albd or vob error logs on host <host name>
```

Here is the background.

1. We were given 2 servers [Registry & view server]
2. Registry server was in island and view server was in under a domain, which is now currently unavailable.
3. We created a new group called "ClearCase" and put both these servers under same LAN and created new users under ClearCase group.
4. While the license & albd service started successfully, it is still unable to create / restore views.
5. We were able to see VOB information via ClearCase explorer, but while trying to create a new view & while accessing the folder, we are getting error like "Encountered an improper argument". Google around this error, we ended up in seeing above error in ClearCase server logs.

Comment: Ok, what the logs are saying? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-2-4-3&lang=en)

Comment: @vonc In RAtionalclearcase/Adminstrator/Logbrowser/vobrpc_server.log

Comment: Sure: what does that log contain?

Comment: vobrpc_server.exe(<pid>): Error: See albd or vob error logs on host <host name>

Comment: Error which I have mentioned here.

Comment: Ok, what the albd or vob log contains on `<hostname>` (you can access it with `getlog` as well)

Comment: If the error tells you to look at the logs on `<hostname>`, that is what you should do.

Comment: Albd(pid): Error: Server vob_server.exe (pid=7224) on "D:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\*.vbs" died on startup; marking it as "down".

Comment: Albd server log shows error like Albd(pid): Error: Server vob_server.exe (pid=7224) on "D:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs*.vbs" died on startup; marking it as "down". and erver vob_server.exe(pid) exited with status 1.

Comment: Now that is the real issue. Can you check the other logs on that same hostname?

Comment: Everything(Vob server, view server, registry server) is running on same host only.

Comment: If I tried run view in different server view logs shows this error :                 view_server.exe(pid): Error: Unexpected error in VOB "pbu-clearcase1:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\*.vbs" op vob_ob_get_vob_owner_sid:error detected by ClearCase subsystem
See vobrpc_server_log on host <host_name>

Comment: Sure what the other logs say on the hostname?

Comment: I mean what the other error logs contain on the same `<hostname>`

Comment: yeah.. 1.view server log error :view_server.exe(pid): Warning: Unable to open vob '<host_name>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs': unknown error in VOB. 2)view_server.exe(7876): Error: Unexpected error in VOB "<host_name>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs" op vob_ob_get_vob_owner_sid:error detected by ClearCase subsystem
See vobrpc_server_log on host <host_name>... 3)vobrpc_server.exe(1188): Error: Problem starting vob_server for vob <host_name>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\esg.vbs. server

Comment: 4)Albd(5364): Error: Server vob_server.exe (pid=7224) on "E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs" died on startup; marking it as "down".. 5)vob_server.exe(pid): Error: No group "clearcase" found.. 6)vob_server.exe(7224): Error: Unknown style protections: 7)cccredmgr(6388): Error: Trouble contacting registry on host "<host_name>": timed out trying to communicate with ClearCase remote

Comment: Whatever I mentioned these are the error present in log files. My host is in clearcase group.while I create the views, It is created default under None group.

Answer (score 0):

The actual errors are:

> 1. view server log error:

```
    view_server.exe(pid): Warning: Unable to open vob 
    '<host_name>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs': 
    unknown error in VOB.
```

> 2. view_server.exe(7876):

```
    Error: Unexpected error in VOB 
    "<host_name>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs" 
    op vob_ob_get_vob_owner_sid:error detected by ClearCase subsystem 
    See vobrpc_server_log on host <host_name>...
```

> 3. vobrpc_server.exe(1188):

```
    Error: Problem starting vob_server for vob
    <host_name>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\esg.vbs. server
```

> 4. Albd(5364):

```
    Error: Server vob_server.exe (pid=7224) on 
    "E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs" 
    died on startup; marking it as "down".
```

> 5. vob_server.exe(pid):

```
    Error: No group "clearcase" found.
```

> 6. vob_server.exe(7224):

```
    Error: Unknown style protections.
```

> 7. cccredmgr(6388):

```
    Error: Trouble contacting registry on host "<host_name>": 
    timed out trying to communicate with ClearCase remote
```

There seems to be an issue with the owner or the groups associated with the Vob.

I would recommend trying [using fix_prot](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146535) for fixing the vob.
And/or [`cleartool protectvob`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146535) to change/reset ownership and group membership.